# how do I resolve /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconfig++ error

Tags: c++

I am getting this error. How do I resolve this?
GNU ld version is GNU ld version 2.15.92.0.2 20040927

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconfig++
```

Comment: Install `libconfig++` perhaps with  `sudo aptitude install libconfig++-dev`; then be careful about the order of arguments to the `gcc` compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I installed libconfig++ and its installed at /usr/local/lib but I still get the error... What do I miss?

Comment: Show your precise compile (and build) command. I suspect you may miss some `-L` arguments... BTW, what distribution, operating system, compiler, builder are you using...? Why don't you install a packaged version of `libconfig++` (development package)?

Answer (score 0):

`cannot find -lconfig++` means it cannot find the `config++` library (in your standard paths and whereever it looks).

You need to install that library. On Debian, you often need the developer version of a package.